# How to generate Vimeo unauthenticated access token?

Tags: api, oauth, token, vimeo-api

I am new to [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/)'s api, i am looking for a way to make unauthenticated requests. I find out that i will need to [generate unauthenticated access token](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#unauthenticated-requests), but i don't see any option to do that in the Vimeo's [apps console](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps). Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app page does not yet support manual construction of unauthenticated access tokens (it's coming!). For now you have to request them programmatically.

Luckily, they don't expire, so you only have to generate it once. Here's a quick walk-through on how to generate this token.

1. Grab your client id and secret from your app page.
2. Slam them together with a colon in the middle (eg abcd1234:edgh678)
3. Base64 encode that whole string (you can find encoders online, plenty of public websites)
4. Construct the request (you can use curl, [a browser tool](http://hurl.it), or your favorite http request tool).

   - HTTP Method: `POST`
   - HTTP URL: `https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client`
   - HTTP Headers: `Authorization: basic <your base 64 encoded token>`
   - Request Body: `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public%20private`

Comment: in some documetation i see bearer authorization header. Is basic different that beare, can you explain why we prefers basic that bearer in this request?

Comment: You use the token with the bearer header. You create a token with the basic header.

Answer (score 5):

The auth header is no longer made available through the apps page on the Vimeo Developer site. Instead, you'll need to build the auth header yourself with the token encoded in base64 like so:

```
'Authorization: basic ' + base64(client_id + ':' + client_secret)
```

Where `client_id` and `client_secret` can be found on your apps page. The final header you should use will look like this:

```
Authorization: basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: is base64()  a function? what about if i am using curl , can i still use base64()?

Answer (score 1):

A good way using `requests_oauthlib`, `request`, and `oauthlib`:

```
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
access_token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url= 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client', auth=self.auth)
```

Comment: The import : `from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session; import requests; from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient`