# Vimeo API - generate unauthenticated token with WP HTTP API

Tags: php, python-requests, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to [get an unauthenticated token from Vimeo's current API v3](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#generate-unauthenticated-tokens), in order to use it to get a simple list of my own videos on my own website. I'm using a WordPress HTTP API function 'wp_remote_post' to generate a proper http request.

According to Vimeo, this is the correct way to do this and it's done with a POST request. Here are the arguments:

```
HTTP Method: POST
HTTP URL: api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client
HTTP Headers: Authorization: basic, base64_encode( "$client_id: $client_secret" )
Request Body: grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public%20private
```

[image]

and getting

```
[body] => {"error":"You must provide a valid authenticated access token."}
[raw] => HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

Why is Vimeo asking for a valid authenticated access token on an explicitly UNauthenticated call? I have provided the actual client id and client secret from my Vimeo app, using Vimeo's instructions to *receive* an *unauthenticated* access token. I'm sending the request from my local environment.

I have checked the similar question [How to generate Vimeo unauthenticated access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613796/how-to-generate-vimeo-unauthenticated-access-token) and have followed everything outlined there. No dice, and i've been trying to do this for hours.

Comment: Bwahaha - driveby downvote? I don't think so. The previous q&a did NOT answer my question at all. I've been researching this question for 6 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimeo API seems to only accept the parameters as **part of the query string**, not as part of the HTTP POST object ('body', 'data', or other).

Only when I coded the parameters directly into the URL, rather than passing them as parameters in the post object, the post worked.

Works:

```
$url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public%20private';
$auth = base64_encode( $developer_key . ':' . $secret_key );
$headers = array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            );
$args = array(
                'headers'     => $headers
            );
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
```

Does Not Work:

```
$url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client';
$auth = base64_encode( $developer_key . ':' . $secret_key );
$data = array(
 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
 'scope' => 'public private'
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);
$args = array(
    'headers'     => $headers,
    'data'        => $data
);
```

Hmmm. [As of WordPress 4.6](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/27/http-api-in-4-6/), the WP_HTTP class is now built on [Requests](http://requests.ryanmccue.info) by Ryan McCue.

So it seems my question is really also a question about how wp_remote_post() constructs the request. There does not seem to be a way to pass the parameters to the function and have them stringified in the URL.